# How to return a function from inside a switch-case statement

Tags: swift, function, return, switch-statement, completionhandler

How can I abort or return the parent function in this case:

```
enum MyError: String, Error {
case serverError = "This is a server error"
case condition1NotTrue = "Condition 1 is not true"
}

func myServerFunction(finishesSuccessful:Bool, completionHandler: @escaping (Result<Void, MyError>) -> Void) {
    if finishesSuccessful {
        completionHandler(.success(()))
    } else {
        completionHandler(.failure(.serverError))
    }
}

func myMainFunction(test1:Bool, uploadToServer:Bool, completionHandler: @escaping (Result<Void,MyError>) -> Void) {
    // check that condition test1 is true
    if !test1 {
        completionHandler(.failure(.condition1NotTrue))
        return // abort function to not execute the rest
    }
 
    if uploadToServer {
        myServerFunction(finishesSuccessful: false) { result in
            switch result {
            case .success():
                print("Successfully uploaded to server")
            case .failure(let error):
                print("Error uploading to server: \(error.rawValue)")
                completionHandler(.failure(error))
                return // <<<--- Here is my problem
            }
        }
    }

    // if !test1 && upload to server successful -> continue and update local data
    print("Local data will be updated now...")
}

myMainFunction(test1: true, uploadToServer: true) { result in
    switch result {
    case .success():
        print("myMainFunction succeeded")
    case .failure(let error):
        print("myMainFunction failed: \(error.rawValue)")
     }
}
```

Basically what I want to do is check some data, then decide if it should be uploaded to a server. If not it will be used locally only, but if it needs to be uploaded, I have to make sure that this succeeded. Otherwise I don't want to update my local data.

This outputs

> Error uploading to server: This is a server error
> myMainFunction failed: This is a server error
> Local data will be updated now...

The `return` cancelling myMainFunction if test1 is not true works fine and it won't update the local data.
the `return` in case myServerFunction fails doesn't though, as it only stops the switch-case-statement.

Is there a convenient way to return myMainFunction right from there? The only workaround I could imagine is setting a bool in the switch-statement and then calling return after the switch-statement, but it somehow looks weird.

Comment: You should not have any more code in myMainFunction after the call to the server function. This looks like a case of putting to much functionality/logic into one function, you have a completion handler in myMainFunction so use that to evalute the result and take further action.

Comment: It should be the  closure body of myMainFuncton caller where you should handle your actions upon getting Success or Error.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson myMainFunction is where I check if all data could be processed. E.g. the name is not taken, the name is long enough. and - last but not least - if the user is online it has to be uploaded to the server. This is vital - so for me it is a usual condition to be met to create the data locally. Then again I want to call it from several different places in my app - and would always need to have the same action in its completion handler. Thats why I think having one mainFunction to call and only handle the user alert from there is the way to go, and include processing the local data

Comment: But you can surely split that up into different smaller functions? Anyway the main point is that myMainFunction has a completion handler and there is where you should handle the result (and the state logic) of the call to the server and not inside myMainFunction

Comment: myMainFunction is supposed to be the one being called from the UI. I think the main problem is that I want to combine two completion handlers. the one of myMainFunction and the one of myServerFunction (which btw is the split up smaller function). Maybe I rather should change myServerFunction to throw - and if it throws not complete myMainFunction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

following @JoakimDanielson advice I changed myServerFunction to throw instead of failing a completion handler:

```
func myServerFunction(finishesSuccessful:Bool) throws {
    if finishesSuccessful {
        print("Upload to Server successful")
    } else {
        throw MyError.serverError
    }
}
```

Now I can catch the error in myMainFunction

```
if uploadToServer {
    do {
        try myServerFunction(finishesSuccessful: false)
    } catch {
        completionHandler(.failure(.serverError))
        return
    }
}
```